# Unicode Nepali Error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, language-support, unicode

After installing ubuntu 16.04, I am facing proper reading and writing of Nepali Unicode. Half letters are not get mixed as they should be. If I have to write प्र , श्र , त्र and so on..it gets error. Previously working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
As my main WORKING LANGUAGE is Nepali, it's annoying. If the problem persists, I've to go back to ubuntu 14.04. I wish fast help.

P.S: I've updated language support.

Comment: Which input source do you use to type Nepali? Have you tried to install _ibus-m17n_ and use one of the Nepali input methods included there?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The Language setting says 'iBus' keyboard input method system. I use default language of Ubuntu for Nepali. I had installed iBus-m17m also after reading your reply. But the language problem persists. Here is the example of the problem which I am refering:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/lkbv182e8l79f37/Nepali%20Display.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I see. Did you try to switch to the _Nepali (rom (m17n))_ or _Nepali (trad (m17n))_ input source in **System Settings -> Text Entry**? I also have a completely different idea (long shot): Can you, when you use the plain _Nepali_ input source in **Text Entry**, try to set input method "none" in **Language Support** and relogin.

Comment: Sorry sir, couldn't get the proper display of the word,tried all methods you refereed. I think rather than it's being our input problem, may be it's defect of this version of Ubuntu for Nepali language. 

And thanks! While writing in different Nepali font, Kalimati font in Libre Writer, it is working well after installing ibus-m17n. But only on Kalimati font. 

It is expected to be displaying normally, as in any earlier version I could read and work in Nepali without any tweaks.

Comment: So it was fonts related? Yes, there is indeed a fonts bug in 16.04; please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [fonts related bug in Ubuntu 16.04](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1574835).

For instance, in previous Ubuntu versions the package **ttf-devanagari-fonts** was installed when you installed the Nepali language. However, that package is not available in the Ubuntu archive for 16.04. The replacement package, which ought to provide the necessary fonts for Nepali, is **fonts-deva**.

So, Bishal, it would be great if you could install **fonts-deva** from the Ubuntu archive, and confirm that it provides the fonts needed for a correct rendering of Nepali.

When the bug has been fixed, **fonts-deva** will automatically be installed when the Nepali language is installed.

Comment: Thank you sir . The problem is almost solved after installing fonts-deva. Now I can get correct format for Nepali words in Ubuntu system, in any editor. For example I can get correct display of अप्रील (April) in time and date.   And it's true that in this version of Ubuntu, Devnagari fonts are missing. Previously there used to be Nepali, Kokila, Mangal, Kalimati, Lohit Nepali and many more fonts pre-installed.  

But in browsers Firefox and Chrome, I am still getting problem.

Comment: @BishalGautam: fonts-deva includes Chandas, Kalimati, Nakula, Nohit, Sahadeva, Samanata and Samyak, and when the bug has been fixed it will be pre-installed. As regards the browsers, you can explicitly select the appropriate font. In Firefox, for instance: Edit -> Preferences -> Content.

Comment: Thank You a lot !! Problem has been resolved completely!

Comment: @BishalGautam: Great. And thank *you* for calling our attention to the fact that fonts-deva (and a bunch of other fonts-* packages for other languages) were not automatically installed. The bug has been [fixed now](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1574835).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:font-manager/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install font-manager
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

I spent 3 Hrs before I read @Gunnar Hjalmarsson 's answer. And 3hrs after that to figure out why it was not working for me.

Though I was having all desire fonts, I was still seeing श्र as 2 separate characters "श् र" (without space) everywhere. There were some webpages which were showing them as single joint character because they were explicitly mentioning the font family. Here is the sample test I did;

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Deva {
        font-family: Gargi,sans-serif;
        font-size: 120%
    }
</style>
:
<p class="Deva">श्र, त्र, प्र </p>
```

Hence I mentioned supportive font in the setting of most of the editors and browsers which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Enter below mentioned command to install all fonts for Hindi and Nepali.

> apt-get install fonts-indic