# How can I develop keyboard bridge?

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard-layout

I have enabled Hindi typing on Ubuntu from "Settings > Regional & Language > input tools > Hindi". But all the options are having different keyboard layouts which don't fit in corresponding phonetic (Roman) mapping. Moreover there is one more challenge in such mapping that many roman Hindi words (Romanagari) may match to different words in Hindi e.g. `ककचहा`, `कच्छा` and `कक्षा`

So I was looking for the application(or if I can develop it) which works as a bridge between actual keyboard and editor and can suggest /predict appropriate word.

Comment: That doesn't sound like phonetic typing. That sounds like you enabled Hindi-keyboard-layout based input system. What input method did you enable and how did you enable it?

Comment: Agree. I've updated the question.

Comment: Try some of the Hindi input methods provided by `ibus-m17n` package (see https://askubuntu.com/q/142977/158442 for installing and using it). The Swanalekha Malayalam input provides a drop down for selecting specific characters (but not words), but I don't think any of the Hindi methods do so. The Hindi (itrans) method is fairly easy, though: ककचहा is `kakacahaa`, कच्छा is `kacchhaa`, कक्षा is `kakshaa` (or `kaxaa`)

Comment: So I have now installed ibus, ibus-m17n, and  m17n-contrib. Now in `Settings > Regional & Language > Manage Installed Languages > Keyboard Input method system` is already set to ibus. Now from Input tools, under Hindi, I can see Bolnagiri, KaGaPa Phonetic, ad Wx. Nothing new is added. So how will I use itrans?

Comment: I tried Bolnagri, which is almost near what I was looking for. However Ubuntu itself is not printing few characters correctly E,g, `श्र` . It even doen't appear properly on browser . However some websites are showing it correctly. I wonder how. May be they are using some special fonts

Comment: @AmitGupta: There should be quite a few more Hindi options. Did you relogin (or reboot) after having installed `ibus-m17n`?

Comment: I've figured out why were they not being displayed. So added as [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002108/696145) on some other question